# Azure Devops Pipeline Download Fileshare Artifacts Task

Tags: azure, file, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server

I am attempting to download files from my companies network fileshare to my Azure Pipelines $(System.ArtifactDirectory). We use Azure Devops Server 2020.

Naturally, I am using the Download Fileshare Artifacts Task.

When I enter my companies file share server path (which can also be accessed from any computer through the file explorer 'network' button), //our-network.com/path/to/file , I get the "ENOENT: no such file or directory" error.

I know that my server path is correct. However, I am wondering if anybody is familiar with this task.

Am I missing a step to connecting my file server to ADOS? Can this be done programmatically? Is there some reason that my hosted ADOS build agents would not be able to find our file server?

I have done some research, and cannot find a solution. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can the build agent comminicate with the fileshare? For example you could try a ping from the build agent or to access the file share first from the build agent, and then through a pipeline. This could help to investigate the issue.

Comment: The build agent can access any other server on the network. So, I would assume it can communicate with the file share...however I know I never should assume that something works in IT.

Answer (score 0):

The value of **`Fileshare path`** should be the path of the folder where the artifact is in, instead of the path of the artifact.

For example, the path of the artifact on your fileshare server is '**`\server\Artifacts\drop`**'.

The **`drop`** is the name of the artifact you set when publishing it, and the artifact files are in this folder.

On the Download Fileshare Artifacts Task, you should set the value of **`Fileshare path`** field as '**`\server\Artifacts`**' which is same as that when you published the artifact. Not '**`\server\Artifacts\drop`**'.

And the value of **`Artifact name`** should be **`drop`**.

When running the task, it will combine **`Fileshare path`** and **`Artifact name`** as the complete correct path of the artifact ('**`\server\Artifacts\drop`**').

For more details, you can see the document about "[**Download Fileshare Artifacts task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-fileshare-artifacts?view=azure-devops)".

Comment: Hi Bright. Yes I am following the task correctly, and have closely studied the task before asking this question. I understand I wrote my path wrong. My issue is that the path is not found when the pipeline runs this task.